# How many transactions get automatically replayed on both sides of the fork?

Tags: hardforks, replay-attack

There is a lot of talk about possibility of replay attack, but I suspect (and I've seen it claimed) that many (perhaps most or even all) transactions that users issue on one of the chains get replayed automatically on the other. Does someone have some statistics, or a way to get them, about how often (for what percentage of transactions) does this happen?

Note that it's probably very easy to pull this "attack" (perhaps some users may even be doing this inadvertently): to my understanding, it just takes a single node in the network that connects to some nodes that support the HF and some that don't.

Comment: This question specifically asks for a statistic that can be exactly measured; how can answers be expected to "tend to be almost entirely based on opinions"?

Answer (score 3):

I am led to believe that Poloniex (who have listed both ETC and ETH) are replaying transactions intentionally so as to aid the technologically 'less well informed' in getting both balances on their platform.

@Nick Johnson mentioned (somewhere) that people might be also inadvertently replaying transactions. It is not necessarily an 'attack' per se.

Statistics wise.. I don't think any exist.

Hope that helps (a little).

Comment: I confirm that this is probably the case. I made two transactions of 1 eth on the forked chain and they were immediately cloned on the classic chain. i doubt people specifically aimed my accounts and care for 1 eth, so I think this is either a bot or a specific client version. But I admit that I don"t now the aim of replaying all the transactions. What I can't explain is why not all transactions are replayed. For instance, transactions that sent me eth from my mining pool were not replayed. That's a shame, why can't I also have free ETC ? :p

Comment: Transactions of freshly mined coins _cannot_ be replayed on the other chain as these coins don't exists on the other chain. Such transactions will always fail on the other chain. This goes for both ways (ETH->ETC and vice versa). (Note that I don't know whether pools send out freshly mined ether, but they definitely may.)